# compilation error: overloading operator()

Tags: c++

VisualStudio 2008 (VC++ 9)
Problem with overloading operator()

Hello community!

It seems that overloaded version of operator() must all differ in their argument list, independly of the return type.

I have the following case:

```
class Sha256{
public:
   QVector<quint32> operator()(QString const& data);      
   QByteArray operator()(QByteArray const& data);
   QVector<quint32> operator()(QByteArray const& data);   // this is line 168   
   ...
}
```

Last declaration leads to following compilation error:
.\sha256.cpp(168) : error C2556: 'QVector Sha256::operator ()(const QByteArray &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'QByteArray Sha256::operator ()(const QByteArray &)'
        with
        [
            T=uint
        ]

On the other side, following declarations are working:

```
class Sha256{
public:
   QVector<quint32> operator()(QString const& data);
   QByteArray operator()(QByteArray const& data);
   ...
}
```

because they have different arguments.

One way would be to add in the first case an additional argument like

```
QByteArray<quint32> operator()(QByteArray const& data, bool getByteArray)
```

but this is embarassing, not intuitive and also not clean (return type would be a QByteArray, independly of the value of getByteArray, even in case of false!).

Another way could be to use a template function like

```
template<class T> T operator()(QByteArray const& ba)
template<class T> T operator()(QString const& str)
```

but T could only be of a few 'supported' type (QByteArray and QVector), therefore user could run into trouble if using wrong T Type. This version seems to be error prone.

So my questions are:
1. Why is the return type of function objects not taken into account in the signature to distinguish between different flavors of the function like in 'classical' functions?
2. Is there a better way around than adding an additional dummy argument?

Thank you for your valuable time.
Alain

Comment: You can't overload by return type.

Comment: It's because of how the language is designed. First you evaluate a function call, then you end up with a return value. (A *conversion operator* is a different story.)

Comment: @KerrekSB you should expand it in an answer

Comment: Do you only want to use operator()? Wouldn't it be nice to have methods like getVectorSha, getArraySha?

Comment: If you found one of these answers useful, you may want to consider [accepting one of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

Return type is never used for overload resolution. In fact, you can't even declare two functions that differ only in return type. In my opinion, adding this feature would be complicated and not that helpful. Is it necessary to use the function call operator? You could just use a named member function, and then give them different names. Another option would be to use a member template, but even then you would need to explicitly give the return type as a template argument, and the syntax would be ugly if done on the function call operator.

The comment from Kerrek SB suggests a workaround by leveraging conversion operators, if you are okay with something that is complex on the inside, but simpler on the outside.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

A fooA_impl(const char *) {
    std::cerr << "A impl" << std::endl;
    return A();
}
B fooB_impl(const char *) {
    std::cerr << "B impl" << std::endl;
    return B();
}

class Helper {
    public:
        operator A() { return fooA_impl(p); }
        operator B() { return fooB_impl(p); }
    private:
        friend Helper foo(const char *p);
        Helper(const char *p_) : p(p_) {}
        const char *const p;
};

Helper foo(const char *p) {
    return Helper(p);
}

int
main() {
    A a(foo("hello"));
    B b(foo("hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use overload by return type. One thing you can do is to add the return type as a tag parameter when overloading operator():

```
   QByteArray operator()(QByteArray const& data, const QByteArray& tag );
   QVector<quint32> operator()(QByteArray const& data, const QVector<quint32>& tag);
```

The below is how you call these function:(assume both types have default constructors).

```
(data, QByteArray());
(data, QVector<quint32>());
```

Comment: `tag` needs to be const reference for this to work. It could be called by `x = foo(data, x);` though, avoid explicitly naming the type.