# Trouble with templates. Error : Cannot deduce template argument for type 'T'

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to implement templates into the readInSearchCriterion method to handle double/string/Date. Could not deduce template argument for 'T' is the current state.

In UserInterface.cpp

Declaration:

```
template <typename T> T readInSearchCriterion() const;
```

Definition:

```
template<typename T>
T UserInterface::readInSearchCriterion() const
{
T val;
cout << "Enter search value: ";
cin >> val;
return val;
}
```

In CashPoint.cpp, double (amount) stores the search criterion (eg.50)

```
amount = theUI_.readInSearchCriterion();
```

Comment: The return type is never used for deduction.

Comment: You need to specify explicitely the template argument : theUI_.readInSearchCriterion<double>();

Comment: If you want a possible workaround, you can return a helper object then leverage the notion of "convertibility". See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23473231/3521733.

Comment: @galinette when i wrote that it comes up with an unresolved external. How else would I be able to return the variable if the return cannot be used?

Comment: @matt9251 it is not return cannot be used, it is not used for deduction. Those are different things

Comment: how can the value be passed then?

Comment: @matt9251: I think Slava misunderstood. You can just return it as normal. The return *type* is not used for deducing the template arguments. That's all. So if you specify the return type explicitly, then everything else is normal.

Comment: @matt9251: And, if you can't or don't want to specify the return type explicitly, then you can use the workaround I mentioned above.

Comment: @kec i can only explicitly declare the type like so "theUI_.readInSearchCriterion<double>();" which gives an error, cant i?

Comment: That looks okay to me.

Comment: @matt9251 : your declaration AND definition should be in the header, not in the cpp, and included in CashPoint.cpp

Answer (score 1):

When you write a template function:

```
template<class T> void foo( T arg );
```

You suppose to call it specifying type:

```
foo<int>( 1 );
```

In case that compiler can calculate or deduce the type, you can omit the full form and use short form:

```
foo( 1 ); // same as before, <int> deduced from arg type, which is int(1) in this case
```

Compiler is not allowed to deduce from return type by language rules (why so is out of scope of this question) so if you use template type only in return, use full form:

```
template<class T> T foo();
int i = foo<int>(); // ok
int i = foo(); // error
```

This is unrelated to unresolved symbol by linker, that most probably means you put implementation in cpp file, but it must be visible everywhere you use it (or you need to use explicit instanciation for all types it suppose to be used). Simplest solution - put implementation into header.

Comment: if i simply write in "amount = theUI_.readInSearchCriterion<double>();", i get an external error and this is the only place i can declare the type.

Comment: I already put answer to your question. In place where you write "amount = theUI_.readInSearchCriterion<double>();" function **definition**, not only **declaration** must be visible. Or you need to use explicit instantiation.

Comment: the userinterface.h is included within the same cpp as the above statement. How do you use explicit instantiation?

Comment: @matt9251 : put the definition in the userinterface.h, not userinterface.cpp (as for all non fully specialized template definitions)